# Calculating the average value at zero temperature (Coulomb Staircase)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, mean-field-theory

As I was trying to understand slave rotor mean field theory (arXiv:cond-mat/0404334), I have faced a problem while solving the Coulomb staircase example in which I had to calculate the expectation value of some quantity at $T \rightarrow 0$. For an atomic system with two orbitals giving rise to a spin/orbital index of N = 4, we have the average occupancy $\langle\hat{Q}\rangle$

\begin{equation}
\langle\hat{Q}\rangle  = \frac{1}{Z_{at}} \sum_{Q=0}^{N} {N\choose Q} Q e^{-E_Q/T}
\end{equation}

where Q represents the fermionic number and the partition function of electron ensemble in atomic orbitals $Z_{at}$ is

\begin{equation}
Z_{at}  = \sum_{Q=0}^{N} {N\choose Q} e^{-E_Q/T}
\end{equation}

given that the energy is

\begin{equation}
E_Q = \epsilon_0 Q + \frac{U}{2} \left(Q - \frac{N}{2} \right)^2
\end{equation}

Numerically, I can obtain the so-called Coulomb staircase as $T \rightarrow 0$, which gives the dependence of average occupancy on the atomic level position $\epsilon_0$. My question is that, how can I obtain an analytical solution? Is there an approximation that I can do on $e^{-E_Q/T}$ term that give rise to analytical solution?

Just out of curiosity, I have tried to do TS expansion on the exponential coefficient $e^{-E_Q/T}$ goes to zero for T = 0. Ofc it did not work.